# Can't access remote shares on L2TP VPN

Tags: vpn, network-share, windows-10, windows-server-2016, l2tp

I've set up a L2TP VPN for my (Microsoft Surface Pro 4) tablet when I am at work so I can still access my files on my local server.

However when I'm connected to the VPN I can't seem to access my shared files via `\\server.domain.com\share` nor `\\server\share` nor `\\192.168.0.2\share`. I can however `ping server` and it pings just fine.
I can also RDP to my server and I can even access my routers via the webbrowser, but file shares refuse to work.

I port-forwarded `TCP 139`, `TCP 445`, `UDP 137`, `UDP 138` and `UDP 500` and I even set my server as DMZ in my modem/router.

I also have a DistributedCOM event-ID 10016 error going on in my windows 10 system logs, but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this issue.

Could you guys perhaps help me out?

Operating systems:

- Windows Server 2016
- Windows 10

I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xl3BhwLFgB4

Kind regards,

Comment: Did you try to access any other computer share on the same network where server is connected,?

Comment: I'd look at the address ranges first. The most likely issue is a firewall or network policy blocking this sort of traffic going out but since you can ping an ip-address that matches that of your home system I suspect the two networks share the same network address space.